# Trigger pipeline on completion of all dependent pipelines yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline, schedule

I have two different pipelines A and B and need to trigger pipeline C on completion of both pipeline A AND pipeline B. A and B runs on different times and will need to trigger C upon completion of both A and B, and not run if either A or B fails.

Would adding both pipelines, like in the example below code, create an "OR" logic or an "AND" logic to the pipeline?

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: A
      source: A.source
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
    - pipeline: B
      source: B.Source
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
```

I only have experience adding a single pipeline dependency but requirements have changed and wanted to check before posting the above logic.

Answer (score 1):

It works like `OR` and it is impossible to configure this to behave like `AND`. For this, you require state management and this is not provided by Azure DevOps. You could try to build it on your own with some external service and then when you get A and B triggered what satisfies your condition trigger pipeline C via REST API.